# SAP Fiori MyInbox stand-alone isn't working?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to implement *SAP Fiori MyInbox* without using the Fiori Launchpad. The Fiori Launchpad isn't installed on the system and won't be. I found some articles like this one: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/14/how-to-run-my-inbox-app-in-standalone-header-less-mode/

> Launch the following URL in your browser:
>
> ```
> https://<Server>:<Port>/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=<Client>&sap-ushell-config=headerless#Shell-runStandaloneApp?sap-ushell-SAPUI5.Component=cross.fnd.fiori.inbox&sap-ushell-url=/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/ca_fiori_inbox&<other URL parameters>
> ```

But this will also need the Fiori Launchpad to be up and running. *MyInbox* is just a web app. So it should run via a specific link. I tried to test the service `CA_FIORI_INBOX` from SICF but just getting HTTP 404.

System Alias etc. is up and running and the Inbox runs on a local gateway.

Someone of you can tell me if it's possible to run the MyInbox without Fiori-Launchpad?

Comment: "stand alone" here is a misnomer. You can start it without going through the launchpad directly, but it's not designed to run by itself

Answer (score 0):

[(Pic)Runnung Standalone My Inbox as web application in WebIde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr9dc.jpg)

The url which you are referring to is of a fiori launchpad.

Add this index.html file in the same directory as component.js and run the index.html file.

```html
***<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Inbox</title>
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
   src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
   data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
   data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"cross.fnd.fiori.inbox": "./"}'>
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script>
   sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
    new sap.m.Shell({
     app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
      height : "100%",
      name : "cross.fnd.fiori.inbox"
     })
    }).placeAt("content");
   });
  </script>
 </head>***

 <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
 </body>

</html>
```

Genarally Fiori Apps uses Component.js file to run from fiori launchpad. The fiori launch pad acts as a container for this apps. To run standalone, we need html.

Comment: what I asked is if it's possible to run the myinbox without installed Fiori Launchpad.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely . It can be ran as a standalone app as long as index.html is present. Make sure the Taskprocessing Odata service is available.

Comment: Thank you - i will give it a try. Sounds fairly simple :) OData Service is avaiable.